Unable to access Azure AD SAML mobile app in android 8.0 mobile device
We have an Azure AD enterprise app which supports SAML protocol for authentication. The app is working fine when accessed from system's browser, mobile device browser or when installed on personal Android /iOS device. However, when the same app is installed on MDM-registered device, the app is not accessible. The app can be accessed from the browser on the same device. The device is controlled by VMWare Workspace. The VMware team has also configured the SSO configs for this app in order to access it from the registered device. We are unable to see any sign-in attempts in the AAD sign in logs when the app is accessed from the registered Android device. (installed one) However, when it is accessed from the same device's browser, it is recorded in AAD sign-in logs. We are using PTA authn in our hybrid AAD environment. So the requests are going to ADFS from AAD for completing authN. When the app is accessed from browser, user gets the ADFS prompt to enter his creds, but not when the installed app is accessed. The user is getting the error page after entering his AAD creds. (error is attached.)
